# My react onClick function doesnt work on first click, works subsequent clicks. And my setAnswers on line 90, doesnt re-render component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to build a survey creator app with react. I dynamically add questions and answers from each question. But my Add answer button doesnt work on first click. I printing questions when I click add answer button. Its printing empty array on console. But doesnt add answer. Also when I click delete answer button, it adds another answer first. Then second click, it deletes which answer I clicked. But this setAnswer hook doesnt re-render component.

Here is my codes:

`

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  const addQuestion = () => {
    let question = [
      ...questions,
      {
        questionID: questions.length,
        questionData: "",
        answers: answers?.filter(
          (answerItem) => answerItem.questionID === questions.length
        ),
      },
    ];
    setQuestions(question);
  };

  const addAnswer = (questionItem) => {
    
    var answer = [
      ...answers,
      {
        answerID: answers.length,
        answerData: "",
        questionID: questionItem.questionID,
      },
    ];

    setAnswers(answer);
    questionItem.answers = answers.filter(
      (answerItem) => answerItem.questionID === questionItem.questionID
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-900 text-white h-auto block flex flex-col items-center">
      <button
        id="btn-add-question"
        type="submit"
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={() => {
          addQuestion();
        }}
      >
        Add Question
      </button>
      <div>
        {questions.map((questionItem) => (
          <div className="" key={questionItem.questionID}>
            <div className="questionContainer border border-solid border-white p-4 mb-5 mt-5">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <h1>Question: </h1>
                <input
                  className="shadowborder ml-5 rounded w-full"
                  type="text"
                  name="questionContent"
                  id="questionContent"
                  placeholder="Enter question content..."
                />
                <button
                  id="btn-add-answer"
                  type="submit"
                  className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded w-48 h-10 ml-5"
                  onClick={() => {
                    addAnswer(questionItem);
                    console.log(answers);
                  }}
                >
                  Add answer
                </button>
              </div>
              {questionItem.answers?.map((answerItem) => (
                <div key={answerItem.answerID} className="flex items-center">
                  <h1>Şık: </h1>
                  <input
                    className="shadowborder rounded w-full ml-5 mb-1 mt-2 text-black"
                    type="text"
                    name="answerContent"
                    id="answerContent"
                    placeholder="Enter an answer..."
                  />
                  <button
                    className=" ml-5 border w-16"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      setAnswers(
                        answers.filter(
                          (a) => a.answerID !== answerItem.answerID
                        )
                      );
                      console.log(answers);
                    }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

I'm new in React, I think I add answer when I first click to addAnswer button, but It prints one missing. When I click to delete button, it prints missing answer first, and deletes question when I click second time. Sorry for my bad English and typos.

In the screenshot, I have an 6 items in answer array, but browser showing 5.

[image]

Comment: can you attach the screenshot?

Comment: state updates are maybe async, and when you log the value right after setting state you cannot see the change immediately until next render ... you can log the value outside the handler (in component function body) and see the changes

Comment: I edited and added screenshot now